# Decimal.TryParse doesn't parse my decimal value

Tags: c#, decimal, tryparse

When I tried to convert something like 0.1 (from user in textbox), My value b is always false.

```
bool b = Decimal.TryParse("0.1", out value);
```

How can it be here to work?

Comment: What is your locale?

Comment: it is working for me, did you mention value before using it?

Comment: Nikhil, if the return value is `false` then it's very much irrelevant.

Comment: I just tried this in Mono, sorry not near a windows box atm, and the method works.  Is this your exact code?  What is the type of your out variable?  Can you check your out variable, is it populated?

Comment: My code exactly is now:            bool isFutureValueDecimal = Decimal.TryParse("0.1", out futurevalue);


            if (isFutureValueDecimal == false)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Too late to the party, but I was going to suggest forcing the culuture to en-US but Invariant is a better sln

```
decimal value;
bool b = Decimal.TryParse("0.1", NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out value);
```

Answer (score 48):

Specify the culture for the parsing. Your current culture uses some different number format, probably `0,1`.

This will successfully parse the string:

```
bool b = Decimal.TryParse("0.1", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value);
```

Comment: This is the real solution

Answer (score 10):

Use `Culture` in overload method